# routing in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am having a raspberry pi3 where someone had already set it up. Wifi is accessible from it but when I search through google or any website it is routing me through Brazil. when I open google, it goes to google brazil. How can I route through usa. Please gide me through steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see http://rohankapoor.com/2012/04/americanizing-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you. The article helped.

Answer (score 0):

In case the tutorial in the [comments](http://rohankapoor.com/2012/04/americanizing-the-raspberry-pi/) does not work for you.

You have the next options from the official documentation at:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

> ***Internationalization options***
>
> Select Internationalization Options and
>   press Enter to be taken to a sub-menu containing the following
>   options:
>
> ***Change locale***
>
> Select a locale, for example en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8.
>
> ***Change timezone***
>
> Select your local timezone, starting with the region
>   such as Europe, then selecting a city, for example London. Type a
>   letter to skip down the list to that point in the alphabet.
>
> **Change keyboard**
>
> layout This option opens another menu which allows you
>   to select your keyboard layout. It will take a long time to display
>   while it reads all the keyboard types. Changes usually take effect
>   immediately, but may require a reboot.